# Can you change the order of fields in Jira?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to change the order of fields appearing in Jira?

Comment: Answer: yes. Screens also exist in all versions of JIRA back to 3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Jira 5, you can define the order of fields in a **[screen](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+a+Screen)**:

[image: Jira Screen]

> - In the **`Add Field`** form towards the end of the Configure Screen page, select the field/s that you wish to add to the screen from the Fields to add list.
> - (info) If you wish, specify the number representing the position to which a field should be added relative to the other fields.
> - (tick) Use the numbers indicated in the table's Position column as a guide.
>     at which the field will be placed, by entering the position number in the Position option.
> - (info) If you have selected multiple fields and specified a position, the topmost field selected will be placed in the corresponding position and the other fields directly below it.
> - Click the Add button.

So if you have access to the administration part of Jira, where you can define/update the screens associated with a given form, then yes, you can define the order of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not available in JIRA OnDemand, only in JIRA download version...